# How to change props of header dynamically on every page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am very new to React, I have got a multipage app with a header bar component that is reused on every page.

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.authenticated) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <header className="topHeader">
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

I then pass this to App.js (with the title hard coded as "hi" for now):

```
...return (
      <div className="masterContainer">
        <Router>
          <Header authenticated={this.state.authenticated} title="hi" />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login"
              component={() => (
                <LoginPage
                  updateUser={() => this.loadCurrentlyLoggedInUser()}
                />
              )}
            /> ...
```

In the page component itself, I have a blank page for now:

```
class Messages extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="messages">
        <h2>Test page - Messages</h2>
        <br />
        <h2>This is a private page</h2>
        <p>
          You could only access this page after logged in.
          <br />
          Changes to the token or user logged out will redirect the user to the
          login page.
        </p>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

Now, I want to set a title on the blank page (as title="Messages") but I only know how to pass one prop to another. But I do not know how to have the prop from the blank page, to App.js, then back to the Header component.

Any tips on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a method handle to your page component as props. And you Page component can callback the handle component.

There are other advanced ways also like Context API, Redux etc.

App.js

```
state = { title:'' };

setHeaderTitle = (title) => {
 this.setState({ title });
}

...return (
      <div className="masterContainer">
        <Router>
          <Header authenticated={this.state.authenticated} title={this.state.title} />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login"
              component={() => (
                <LoginPage setHeaderTitle={this.setHeaderTitle}
                  updateUser={() => this.loadCurrentlyLoggedInUser()}
                />
              )}
            /> ...
```

Page component

```
class Messages extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
   this.props.setHeaderTitle("Page Title");
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="messages">
        <h2>Test page - Messages</h2>
        <br />
        <h2>This is a private page</h2>
        <p>
          You could only access this page after logged in.
          <br />
          Changes to the token or user logged out will redirect the user to the
          login page.
        </p>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

Comment: Are you passing it like this? `<LoginPage setHeaderTitle={setHeaderTitle}`?

Comment: After I have added "setHeaderTitle={setHeaderTitle}", there is an error of "'setHeaderTitle' is not defined", do you know what that means?

Comment: "setHeaderTitle={setHeaderTitle}" resulted in 'setHeaderTitle' is not defined

Comment: In you App.js you added this code block `setHeaderTitle = (title) => {
 this.setState({ title });
}`?

Comment: Yes, added that. Right before render()

Comment: of set it like this `<LoginPage setHeaderTitle={this.setHeaderTitle}`, you need to add `this` as this is class based component